# ASYNC SOQL "Do Not Have Permission To Query This Object Using ASYNC SOQL"

Tags: async-soql

We have purchased extra Big Objects space from Salesforce which I was advised was a requirement in order to use ASYNC SOQL.

I am now faced with this issue which I run into every time I try to Query an object using ASYNC SOQL. I read somewhere that it needs actually be activated by salesforce as a Feature Activation.

Has anyone any experience with this?

Comment: Have you reached out to Salesforce? You should have got the Async SOQL with the purchase based on how its mentioned in the [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/big_objects/units/big_objects_get_started) -- Async SOQL is included only with the licensing of additional big object capacity.

Comment: Yes I did. They have activated this but there seems to be a lot of problems around the material that they are pushing out to the market around what is possible with this feature and what actually works. They are trying to resolve this internally at the moment. For now I wouldn't purchase this unless you are 100% sure that it does what it says on the tin.